# Difficulties in styling CSS form

Tags: html, css

With all the *controversy* surrounding tables as a layout option for forms, I've decided to go with an unordered list. I finally have the labels and elements displaying as I intend, however the 'note' div I've added refuses to line up with the inputs above it.

I've included the code below, please excuse the garish background colours I've chosen to help me judge placement! Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this the 'note' div refuses to play along?  I'm sure there's a simple solution but I'm completely stumped. Thank you very much in advance.

```
form.contact label
{
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
}
form.contact input
{
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 15em;
}
form.contact .note
{
    margin-left: 15em;
    width: 176px;
    background: yellow;
}
form.contact ul
{
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
}
form.contact ul li
{
    float: left;    
    clear: left;    
    width: 100%;    
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background: pink;
    left: 0;
}

<ul>
        <li>
            <label for="address1">Address Line 1:</label>
            <input name="address1" type="text" id="address1" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="address2">Address Line 2:</label>

            <input name="address2" type="text" id="address2" /> 
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="address3">Address Line 3:</label>
            <input name="address3" type="text" id="address3" /> 
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="address4">Address Line 4:</label>
            <input name="address4" type="text" id="address4" /> 
            <div class="note">This is a note</div>

        </li>

        <li>
            <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit" />
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: You forgot to include the `<form class="contact">` opening tag and the `</form>` closing tag in your html code snippet.

Comment: There is no controversy concerning tables for layout. It just isn't done, period.

Comment: I'm aware that tables are a definite no-no when it comes to layout. I have however read that tables are still the logical option for tabulated data - and whether or not a form counts as such seems to be a grey area.

Comment: remember you are paid to get a **result** by the customer and if a table gets the result then a table is OK, privided it does not give your customer problems.  Simple forms can work well in tables and the two columns (lables, values) does make sence from a logical stand point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the `input` and the `div` have a different font size by default, and using elastic layout with `em` measurements is affected by the size of the font.

This fixes it:

`* {font-size: 12px;}`

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much Finbarr, I've definitely learnt something there.

Comment: Yea, be careful with `em` measurements as they will trip you up.

Answer (score 0):

input is inline element and div.note is block element.  Browsers' default css has different settings for inline elements and div.notes.  I suggest you try to adjust `magin-left` and/or `padding-left` values of input and .note.  You may also need to sepeficy `font-size` as Finbarr points out.

Comment: All sorted thanks to Finbarr's solution, thank you too for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of answers spring to mind.
First, have you considered the defualt padding? I see you specify the margin, but if you haven't included a fixed padding level, the different elements might inherit it differently.

It would also be helpful if you could post a screenshot - the sample code you provided works perfectly for me when I test it in konqueror & firefox - so maybe its a browser issue?

...ok, I see weakish has already said pretty much the same thing while I was typing this. But, my screenshot comment stands; it would be helpful to see exactly what the error is, as you see it.

Comment: All sorted thanks to Finbarr's solution, thank you too for your help.